# python, changing functions into classes and objects

Tags: python

There is a lot of code below but you dont have to really read any of it, you just need to know that the functions exist and the function names. I will describe my problem first.

I have created a procedural program based entirely on functions and a few global variables as you can see below. I want to change the program into an object-oriented-program but I am having trouble with it since I have never done anything like this before.

The procedure that needs to be followed is that:
- the function `attack()` needs to be placed into a file named attacker.py
-the functions `defence()`,`updateVars()`, and `smartDefender()` need to be placed into a file defender.py
-the `main()` function and the rest of the code(most of the code) will be placed in a file named manager.py which will be the main file and will bring everything together.
-I have to use classes.

I have tried a range of different things including changing the names of the functions to `__init__` and then importing and attempting to use them in manager.py. I have also tried to keep the function names the same and just put the functions inside of classes and import attacker.py and defender.py into manager.py but nothing seems to work... Any and all help would be appreciated.

Although I don't think you really need a description of what the program does, if you really need one, I can make a brief one, or you can view it [here.](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~tamj/231/assignments/assignment5/index.htm)

Any and all help will be appreciated.

```
import random

HIGH= 3
MED= 2
LOW= 1

def attack(attackList):

    x= random.uniform(0,1)
    for attackLevel,probability in attackList:
        if x<probability:
            break
        x=x-probability
    return attackLevel





def defence(attackLevel,defendList):

    x= random.uniform(0,1)
    for defendLevel,probability in defendList:
        if x<probability:
            break
        x=x-probability
    return defendLevel





def updateVars(attackLevel,defendLevel,block,hit,run):

    if attackLevel==1:
        printAttackLevel='Low'
    if attackLevel==2:
        printAttackLevel='Medium'
    if attackLevel==3:
        printAttackLevel='High'
    if defendLevel==1:
        printDefendLevel='Low'
    if defendLevel==2:
        printDefendLevel='Medium'
    if defendLevel==3:
        printDefendLevel='High'



    if attackLevel==defendLevel:
        block=block+1
        hit=hit
        run=run+1
    else:
        block=block
        hit=hit+1
        run=run+1

    return block,hit,run,printAttackLevel,printDefendLevel





def smartDefender(defendLevel,attackLevel,smartList):

    for i in smartList:
        if (i==(i+1)==(i+2)):
            defendLevel= attackLevel
            return defendLevel
        else:
            return






def main():

    DEFAULT_PROBABILITY= 0.33
    run=0
    hit=0
    block=0
    smartList=[]


    rounds= int(input("\nPlease enter the number of rounds between 1 and 100:"))
    if rounds<=0 or rounds>100:
        print("\n")
        print("Invalid range. The number of rounds has been set to 10 by DEFAULT_PROBABILITY.")
        rounds=10


    lowAttackProb= float(input("\nPercentage of attacks aimed low(0-100):"))/100
    medAttackProb= float(input("Percentage of attacks aimed medium(0-100):"))/100
    highAttackProb= float(input("Percentage of attacks aimed high(0-100):"))/100
    if lowAttackProb+medAttackProb+highAttackProb !=1.00:
        print("\n")
        print("Invalid entry. The sum of the pecentages must equal 100%. The probability of each level has been set to 33.0% by DEFAULT_PROBABILITY.")
        lowAttackProb=DEFAULT_PROBABILITY
        medAttackProb=DEFAULT_PROBABILITY
        highAttackProb=DEFAULT_PROBABILITY


    print('\nLet The Fighting Begin')
    print('-'*22)


    while  run < rounds:

        lowDefProb= DEFAULT_PROBABILITY
        medDefProb= DEFAULT_PROBABILITY
        highDefProb= DEFAULT_PROBABILITY


        attackList= [(LOW,lowAttackProb),(MED,medAttackProb),(HIGH,highAttackProb)]
        attackLevel= attack(attackList)
        smartList.append(attackLevel)
        defendList=[(LOW,lowDefProb),(MED,medDefProb),(HIGH,highDefProb)]
        defendLevel=defence(attackLevel,defendList)
        block,hit,run,printAttackLevel,printDefendLevel= updateVars(attackLevel,defendLevel,block,hit,run)
        if run>(rounds/2):
            defendLevel=smartDefender(defendLevel,attackLevel,smartList)
            #implement smart mode

        print('%s%2s%s%3s%s%5s%s%3s'% ('\nRound',run,':\t','Attacker:',printAttackLevel,'\t','Defender:',printDefendLevel))


    print("%2s%2d%s%s%2d"% ('\nTotal Hits:',hit,'\t','Total Blocks:',block))
    print('Attacker Proportions:','','','Low:','','',lowAttackProb*100,'%','','','Medium:','','',medAttackProb*100,'%','','','High:','','',highAttackProb*100,'%')
    print('Defender Proportions:','','','Low:','','',lowDefProb*100,'%','','','Medium:','','',medDefProb*100,'%','','','High:','','',highDefProb*100,'%')
    print("\nThank you for using this program, Goodbye!")





main()
```

My question is, How can I very easily (not necessarily efficiently) convert these procedural program into a object-oriented one that uses classes and multiple files.

I think problem areas would include where the functions are being called in `main()`, if that helps to solve the problem at all..

Comment: OK, you have fine tech spec. So, what is your question?

Comment: My question is, How can I very easily (not necessarily efficiently) convert these procedural program into a object-oriented one that uses classes and multiple files...if that makes sense..? the question is in the OP in more detail.

Comment: Seems like you're confusing classes and modules. Renaming functions to `__init__` doesn't make a program OO.

Comment: I am very confused and new to this. very confused...

Comment: @SajSeesSound Don't try and *convert* your code. Instead, start with a blank slate and think of what objects exist in your system (if it were real, what *things* would there be?), then, create a class for each thing. Then move the behaviour described in your existing code to your classes to describe the object's behaviour, updating it as needed.

Comment: OK, you need three entity (class): Attacker, Defender and Manager, you have ugly procedural code (ugly even for procedural) and I think you can't to use it more for OOP version.

Comment: @Denis you should have seen my procedural code 3-4 programs ago, now that was ugly code... I tried implementing minimum number of functions here.

Comment: @Lattyware I think that because of my lack of understanding of classes I would not be able to that in time for the deadline, if you cannot directly help then can you lead me to a very easy to follow tutorial, I have had no luck finding those in respect to classes.

Comment: @SajSeesSound Do not take my words to heart you are learning and this is normally. I save link to this question and write some skeleton for you when I will be at home ))

Comment: @Denis ,Thanks, but when would that be?

Comment: @SajSeesSound Sounds like you need to go back and understand object orientation (it's really not hard, it's just treating code like real things). If you have a deadline you are not going to meet, then you should have started working earlier. There is no shortcut to learning and understanding. Anything beyond what I have said that anyone else gives you won't help you actually improve, it'll just be a shortcut that will mean you don't have to learn it. What you are asking now is for someone to do your work for you, or hold your hand and walk you through it - that's not what SO is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it helps ... I just made this class-based script as an example.

```
class Car():

    def __init__(self, mileage=0, mpg=10, tank_capacity=5):
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.mpg = mpg
        self.tank_capacity=tank_capacity
        self.tank_level = 0                

    def drive(self, miles):
        gallons_burned = float(miles) / self.mpg
        if self.tank_level < gallons_burned:
            miles_driven = float(self.tank_level) * self.mpg
            self.tank_level = 0
            self.mileage += miles_driven
            print "You ran out of gas after %s miles." % miles_driven
            return
        self.tank_level -= gallons_burned
        self.mileage += miles
        print "You made it to your destination after %s miles." % miles

    def pump_gas(self, gallons):
        self.tank_level += gallons
        if self.tank_level > self.tank_capacity:
            self.tank_level = self.tank_capacity
        print "You now have %s gallons in your tank" % self.tank_level

    def status(self):
        print "Mileage:", self.mileage
        print "Tank level: %s gallons" % self.tank_level

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_car = Car(mileage=100, mpg=30, tank_capacity=3)
    my_car.pump_gas(4)
    my_car.status()
    my_car.drive(50)
    my_car.status()
    my_car.drive(60)
    my_car.status()

"""
You now have 3 gallons in your tank
Mileage: 100
Tank level: 3 gallons
You made it to your destination after 50 miles.
Mileage: 150
Tank level: 1.33333333333 gallons
You ran out of gas after 40.0 miles.
Mileage: 190.0
Tank level: 0 gallons
"""
```

Comment: Good old classic example ))

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enought time right now but I place here part of code which should help you, later  I add more

```
import random


class Attacker(object):
    def __init__(self, power):
    """In this method you can assign
        variables or perform actions which
        you want to perform on object create"""

        #for example on object create we want
        #to set strenght of attacker
        #so this variable will live and
        #availiable for object whole it's
        #life
        self.power = power

    def attack(self):
    """So attacker must can attack
        for example this method just
        return random int multiple on self.power 
        later we compare value of from defender's
        defend method and decide who is
        winner of round"""

        return random.randint(100) * self.power
```